# Paypal testing account 3005 error Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to set up a Paypal payments on Wordpress using Restricted Content Pro plugin.

But while procceding to payment on sandbox account it throws 3005 error.

Here video with that error :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKyYA9UU7mo&feature=youtu.be

Anyone got smilar problem and know the solution?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache and cookies? Generally this error means the cookies need cleared, but it is a very generic error. Also, are you using the Sandbox buyer account to try to make payment?

Answer (score 0):

You input your live PayPal account team@traineffective.com in your plugin, please input your sandbox seller account team-facilitator@traineffective.com  in your plugin, then this 3005 error should be fixed.

Comment: While this is a very useful information, it doesn't answer the question. Please add it as a comment to the question.